# Import and Develop an ionic v2 project in Android Studio

Tags: angularjs, android-studio, ionic2

I created a Ionic project in Ionic v2. I earlier worked with ionic V1 in V1 I can import the project with Android Studio and develop it. The folder structure platform/android/assets in an Ionic v2 project is totally different from an Ionic v1 project. There is no page in platform/android/assets. I got error in installed apk when I develop apk using Android Studio. Is there any way I can import and  develop the ionic v2 project with Android Studio?

Comment: Why would you want to alter the code of the Android platform files? They will be re-generated when you run ionic build android again.

Comment: No I don't need to alter the Android platform file.But i need to change the src folder including htm,typescript file for my development using Android  studio